# Не удается написать цикл для суммы чисел

Tags: python, циклы, while

Надо написать программу с циклом, которая просит ввести ряд положительных чисел. При введении отрицательного числа, цикл прекратится.

После введения всех положительных чисел, программа должна вывести их сумму. Я применил цикл `while` и ввел накопитель, но при таком методе отрицательное число тоже попадает в накопитель и искажает результат.

```
print('Введите необходимые числа, программа посчитает их сумму. Для окончания 
работы программы 
введите отрицательное число')
x = float(input('Введите число: '))
total = x
while x >= 0:
    x = float(input('Введите число: '))
    total += x
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
total = 0
while True:
    x = float(input('Введите число: '))
    if x > 0:
        total += x
    else:
        print(total)
        break
```